# Why 'Array()' and not 'new Array()' in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Other objects in PHP are instantiated using the `new` qualifier such as `new Date()`, etc.  How come you do not supply the `new` qualfier with `Array()` when instantiating a new array in PHP?

```
$array = new Array(); //blows up
$array = Array();     //works as intended

$reflect = new ReflectionClass($this);   //works as intended
$reflect = ReflectionClass($this);       //blows up
```

Comment: Can arrays be created using `Array()`(using upper case)? The manual says `array()`(using lower case)

Comment: @AzizAG PHP is case-insensitive for that.

Comment: @PauloFreitas `aRrAy('makes','me','sad :(')`

Comment: @PauloFreitas It actually works, I just tried it, I'm impressed.

Comment: @AzizAG I'm not sure if "impressed" is the correct word for this .. (perhaps "surprised"?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array is a language construct not a class so you cant use new to instantiate an Array object.

Answer (score 2):

Because `array` is syntax, not a class. Same as with `list`, `echo`, and a few others.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you create the "Array" class, it will 'blow up' because PHP doesn't have a built-in Array class.

Array is not a class, but rather a function.

For the same reason you can't do

```
$myvar = new print('hello');
```

That would be crazy, no? `print()`, like `array()`, is a function built into PHP, not a class.

Comment: My object oriented brain wouldn't conceive that `array()` is a function

Answer (score 1):

Array was in php before even object oriented ways was introduced in it

Think of it as C language array which can still be used in C++ :)